# WSo2 Governance Registry 4.6.0 - secondary user store issue

Tags: registry, wso2

I can't get my *secondary user store* to load.

I've tried configuring it using the Governance Registry's Management Console and doing it manually. My secondary user store is Active Directory and I've tried configuring both a `ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager`, and when that didn't work, I tried to use `ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager`. Neither worked.

The wso2carbon.log keeps saying this...

```
TID: [0] [Greg] [2014-05-12 12:03:06,429] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.createSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3442)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3498)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager.deploy(UserStoreDeploymentManager.java:65)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.deploy(UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.java:58)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:810)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:65)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext.<init>(LDAPConnectionContext.java:85)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:148)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
... 26 more
TID: [0] [Greg] [2014-05-12 12:03:06,431]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The deployment of ccad.xml is not valid. {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
```

I've been googling this for days but nothing out there has helped. However, I think the error is similar to this one...
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1943

Anyone know what I can do to make secondary user stores work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the port number in the Connection URL property, when creating the User Store, like this:

ldap://goja.local:389

This is the relevant code snippet:

```
    String rawConnectionURL = realmConfig.getUserStoreProperty(LDAPConstants.CONNECTION_URL);
    String connectionURL = null;
    //if DNS enabled in AD case, this can be null
    if (rawConnectionURL != null) {
        String portInfo = rawConnectionURL.split(":")[2];
```

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown on the last line when the port number is missing.